# What might cause a difficult-to-reproduce truncation of a Hyper HTTP response?

Tags: rust, hyper

I am experiencing a bug where my Hyper HTTP response is being truncated to a specific size (7829 bytes). Making the same request with cURL works fine.

The request queries a JSON endpoint for data. The response struct is then shuffled around a lot, because a relatively complex rate-limiting procedure is used to make a number of these requests at once. However, if only one request is made, the response is still truncated.

Before implementing rate-limiting and doing some heavy refactoring, the program made these responses properly.

I made the minimal example below, but it fails to reproduce the problem. At this point I'm not sure where to look. The codebase is moderately complicated and iteratively expanding the reproduction example is difficult, especially when I don't know what might possibly cause this.

What are some ways that Hyper's Response body might get truncated? The response body is acquired as in the `handle` function below.

```
#![feature(use_nested_groups)]
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate hyper_tls;
extern crate tokio_core;

use futures::{Future, Stream};
use hyper::{Body, Chunk, Client, Method, Request, Response};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let client = Client::configure()
        .connector(HttpsConnector::new(4, &core.handle()).unwrap())
        .build(&core.handle());

    fn handle(response: Response<Body>) -> Box<Future<Item = usize, Error = hyper::Error>> {
        Box::new(
            response
                .body()
                .concat2()
                .map(move |body: Chunk| -> usize { body.len() }),
        )
    }

    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let uri = &args[1];
    let req = Request::new(Method::Get, uri.parse().unwrap());

    let response_body_length = {
        let future = Box::new(client.request(req).map(handle).flatten());
        core.run(future).unwrap()
    };

    println!("response body length: {}", response_body_length);
}
```

Offending code:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
use futures::{future, stream, Future, Stream};
use hyper;
use hyper::{client, Body, Chunk, Client, Headers, Method, Request, Response, header::Accept,
            header::Date as DateHeader, header::RetryAfter};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use models::Bucket;
use std::thread;
use std::time::{Duration, UNIX_EPOCH};
use std::str;

header! { (XRateLimitRemaining, "x-ratelimit-remaining") => [String] }

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Uri(pub String);

const MAX_REQ_SIZE: u32 = 500;

fn make_uri(symbol: &str, page_ix: u32) -> Uri {
    Uri(format!(
        "https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade/bucketed?\
         symbol={symbol}&\
         columns={columns}&\
         partial=false&\
         reverse=true&\
         binSize={bin_size}&\
         count={count}&\
         start={start}",
        symbol = symbol,
        columns = "close,timestamp",
        bin_size = "5m",
        count = MAX_REQ_SIZE,
        start = 0 + MAX_REQ_SIZE * page_ix
    ))
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct RateLimitInfo {
    remaining_reqs: u32,
    retry_after: Option<Duration>,
}

impl RateLimitInfo {
    fn default() -> RateLimitInfo {
        RateLimitInfo {
            remaining_reqs: 1,
            retry_after: None,
        }
    }
    fn from<T>(resp: &Response<T>) -> RateLimitInfo {
        let headers = resp.headers();
        let remaining_reqs = headers
            .get::<XRateLimitRemaining>()
            .unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("x-ratelimit-remaining not on request."))
            .parse()
            .unwrap();
        let retry_after = match headers.get::<RetryAfter>() {
            Some(RetryAfter::Delay(duration)) => Some(*duration),
            _ => None,
        };
        RateLimitInfo {
            remaining_reqs,
            retry_after,
        }
    }
}

fn resp_dated_later<'a>(a: &'a Response<Body>, b: &'a Response<Body>) -> &'a Response<Body> {
    let get_date = |resp: &Response<Body>| {
        let headers: &Headers = resp.headers();
        **headers.get::<DateHeader>().unwrap()
    };
    if get_date(&a) > get_date(&b) {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Query {
    uri: Uri,
    response: Option<Response<Body>>,
}

impl Query {
    fn from_uri(uri: Uri) -> Query {
        Query {
            uri: uri,
            response: None,
        }
    }
}

fn query_good(q: &Query) -> bool {
    match &q.response {
        Some(response) => response.status().is_success(),
        _ => false,
    }
}

type HttpsClient = hyper::Client<HttpsConnector<client::HttpConnector>>;

type FutureQuery = Box<Future<Item = Query, Error = hyper::Error>>;

fn to_future(x: Query) -> FutureQuery {
    Box::new(future::ok(x))
}

fn exec_if_needed(client: &HttpsClient, query: Query) -> FutureQuery {
    fn exec(client: &HttpsClient, q: Query) -> FutureQuery {
        println!("exec: {:?}", q);
        let uri = q.uri;
        let req = {
            let mut req = Request::new(Method::Get, uri.0.parse().unwrap());
            req.headers_mut().set(Accept::json());
            req
        };
        Box::new(
            client
                .request(req)
                .inspect(|resp| println!("HTTP {}", resp.status()))
                .map(|resp| Query {
                    uri: uri,
                    response: Some(resp),
                }),
        )
    }
    if query_good(&query) {
        to_future(query)
    } else {
        exec(client, query)
    }
}

type BoxedFuture<T> = Box<Future<Item = T, Error = hyper::Error>>;

fn do_batch(client: &HttpsClient, queries: Vec<Query>) -> BoxedFuture<Vec<Query>> {
    println!("do_batch() {} queries", queries.len());
    let exec_if_needed = |q| exec_if_needed(client, q);
    let futures = queries.into_iter().map(exec_if_needed);
    println!("do_batch() futures {:?}", futures);
    Box::new(
        stream::futures_ordered(futures).collect(), //future::join_all(futures)
    )
}

fn take<T>(right: &mut Vec<T>, suggested_n: usize) -> Vec<T> {
    let n: usize = if right.len() < suggested_n {
        right.len()
    } else {
        suggested_n
    };
    let left = right.drain(0..n);
    return left.collect();
}

type BoxedResponses = Box<Vec<Response<Body>>>;

fn batched_throttle(uris: Vec<Uri>) -> BoxedResponses {
    println!("batched_throttle({} uris)", uris.len());
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let client = Client::configure()
        .connector(HttpsConnector::new(4, &core.handle()).unwrap())
        .build(&core.handle());

    let mut rate_limit_info = RateLimitInfo::default();

    let mut queries_right: Vec<Query> = uris.into_iter().map(Query::from_uri).collect();

    loop {
        let mut queries_left: Vec<Query> = Vec::with_capacity(queries_right.len());

        println!("batched_throttle: starting inner loop");
        loop {
            // throttle program during testing
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(800));
            println!("batched_throttle: {:?}", rate_limit_info);
            if let Some(retry_after) = rate_limit_info.retry_after {
                println!("batched_throttle: retrying after {:?}", retry_after);
                thread::sleep(retry_after)
            }
            if queries_right.is_empty() {
                break;
            }
            let mut queries_mid = {
                let ri_count = rate_limit_info.remaining_reqs;
                let iter_req_count = if ri_count == 0 { 1 } else { ri_count };
                println!("batched_throttle: iter_req_count {}", iter_req_count);
                take(&mut queries_right, iter_req_count as usize)
            };
            println!(
                "batched_throttle: \
                 queries_right.len() {}, \
                 queries_left.len() {}, \
                 queries_mid.len() {})",
                queries_right.len(),
                queries_left.len(),
                queries_mid.len()
            );
            if queries_mid.iter().all(query_good) {
                println!("batched_throttle: queries_mid.iter().all(query_good)");
                continue;
            }
            queries_mid = { core.run(do_batch(&client, queries_mid)).unwrap() };
            rate_limit_info = {
                let create_very_old_response =
                    || Response::new().with_header(DateHeader(UNIX_EPOCH.into()));
                let very_old_response = create_very_old_response();
                let last_resp = queries_mid
                    .iter()
                    .map(|q| match &q.response {
                        Some(r) => r,
                        _ => panic!("Impossible"),
                    })
                    .fold(&very_old_response, resp_dated_later);
                RateLimitInfo::from(&last_resp)
            };
            &queries_left.append(&mut queries_mid);
        }

        queries_right = queries_left;

        if queries_right.iter().all(query_good) {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!(
        "batched_throttle: finishing. queries_right.len() {}",
        queries_right.len()
    );

    Box::new(
        queries_right
            .into_iter()
            .map(|q| q.response.unwrap())
            .collect(),
    )
}

fn bucket_count_to_req_count(bucket_count: u32) -> u32 {
    let needed_req_count = (bucket_count as f32 / MAX_REQ_SIZE as f32).ceil() as u32;
    return needed_req_count;
}

type BoxedBuckets = Box<Vec<Bucket>>;

fn response_to_buckets(response: Response<Body>) -> BoxedFuture<Vec<Bucket>> {
    Box::new(response.body().concat2().map(|body: Chunk| -> Vec<Bucket> {
        println!("body.len(): {}", body.len());
        println!("JSON: {}", str::from_utf8(&body).unwrap());
        serde_json::from_slice(&body).unwrap()
    }))
}

pub fn get_n_last(symbol: &str, bucket_count: u32) -> BoxedBuckets {
    let req_count = bucket_count_to_req_count(bucket_count);
    let uris = (0..req_count)
        .map(|page_ix| make_uri(symbol, page_ix))
        .collect();

    let responses = batched_throttle(uris);

    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let boxed_buckets = {
        let futures = responses.into_iter().map(response_to_buckets);
        let future = stream::futures_ordered(futures).collect();
        let groups_of_buckets = core.run(future).unwrap();
        Box::new(
            groups_of_buckets
                .into_iter()
                .flat_map(|bs| bs.into_iter())
                .rev()
                .collect(),
        )
    };

    return boxed_buckets;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem better? Are you trying to truncate the response, or is the response coming out truncated? Where are you sending the request to? And what is the expected outcome?

Comment: @E_net4 I have expanded the explanation. Please provide critique if it is still lacking.

Comment: You really should provide the code that actually reproduces the problem.  I could imagine you block the event loop somewhere by (ab)using `Future::wait` (or something else), triggering a timeout on the server which then closes the connection.  Could you at least share `strace -f` ouput (linux only) or a tcpdump of the failing connection?

Comment: @Stefan, I have provided the code. This is exactly the kind of insight I was looking for. I'm not using `Future::wait`. I'm using `stream::futures_ordered(futures).collect()` for concurrently resolving a sequence of futures, and `Core.run` for blocking. To my discomfort I am on Windows, so `strace` is not available. If the solution is not evident given the newly provided code, I'll try and get a tcpdump of the connection.

Comment: You're code still wasn't compiling, and misses a main function.  See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=85446e3dce7ccfaae4260877d695b8eb&version=stable) for what we would have expected from you to put into your question.

Comment: @Stefan, I'll edit my code accordingly in the future. I wasn't aware that playground loads third-party modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first create a `Core` and start lots of requests and gather the `Response` "results".

After you got all the `Response`s you start a new `Core` and try to start reading the data from those `Responses` - but the server probably closed them long ago due to write timeouts, and you only get partial data.

You shouldn't keep the server waiting; start reading the `Responses` as soon as possible.

Comment: *start a new `Core`* — moving the futures between `Core`s also seems highly unusual.

Comment: My erronious understanding was that receiving a response, as you put it, included receiving the whole response and holding it in memory. Could you direct me to an overview of how the process actually works or provide some keywords? I'd like to download the response immediately, and use it arbitrarily later.

Comment: @Shepmaster could you go more indepth about moving futures between `Core`s and why it is unusual?

Comment: Using more than one `Core` often reflects bad design - because it means your code isn't fully async, and it usually should be (instead of switching between async and sync).

Comment: `response.body().concat2()` returns a future that will receive the full response, you just need to drive it.  That probably means restructuring your `batched_throttle` function to use async concepts. I didn't read it fully, but using `thread::sleep` is a nogo in async code, and `for`/`loop` usually is wrong too. You might want to look into `Stream`s and `Future`s.

Comment: @Stefan, thank you for all the information. Very useful. Mixing sync and async mid-processing seems to be the root of my problems. This program doesn't surrender to async structure easily, because there's state and the requests should be executed maximally concurrently. Because the state is batch-level, to make these requests concurrently they have to be made in batches and in sequence. I'll ponder opening a Code Review thread for deriving an async architecture.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis to add to what Stefan said, there *are* times where you want multiple `Core`s, it's just not common, especially for introductory usages. From what I've seen, doing such usually comes about when you mix multithreading with futures, which is a very nuanced topic.